# How to get temp folder path

Tags: web-services, jsp

I am working on a web application. And in application i have to get the path of temp folder of user -PC & its working fine but when i deploy the war file in server Then it give me the path of temp folder of server instead of User-PC. But my goal is to get user-PC 
Temp folder path.
This is what i used to get temp folder:-

```
String temppath=System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
System.out.println("Temp path is "+System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(temppath+"employee.ser");
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fo);
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect to get a path on the client PC via server side code? Obviously your java server code only knows about the paths on the server, and it has no way of knowing paths on the computer (or smartphone or car or whatever connected to internet) accessing your web application.

You can get information about the client configuration with some techniques, using javascript or a java applet (and possibly other options), but unless you explicitely ask your client's permission, this is something you never should do (as it's akin to breaking and entering in your client's computer).

Now about you *"needing to get the path of temp folder of user pc"*: what do you need that for? If you want to store some informations on your client's computer with a web app, you need to use web technologies for that (and they are subject to the client's autorisation), like cookies (the most old school way) or the new html 5 local storage api.